# Why OpenCV SimpleBlobDetector only works on the image saved by using matplotlib.pyplot.savefig() but not the one by cv2.imwrite()?

Tags: python, opencv, openai-gym

First of all, I am trying to generate images of the simulation environment OpenAI Gym. What I get is a `128 x 128 x 3` numpy.ndarray, which is assigned to the variable `state`. This image contains a target object, and I want to detect the object by using the `SimpleBlobDetector` in `cv2` (opencv).

So far, I have tried three ways to achieve this goal. 
1. use the variable `state` as the input of `SimpleBlobDetector`
2. use `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig()` to save the variable `state` as `test_mat.png`, then restore the image as the input of `SimpleBlobDetector`.
3. Do the same as 2. except for using `cv2.imwrite()` to save the image.

The following is how I store the images:

```py
import gym
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
env = gym.make('Reacher-v2')
state = env.reset()
print("State:",state.shape) # (128, 128, 3)

# save the image with matplotlib
%matplotlib inline
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(state)
plt.savefig('test_mat.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
plt.show()


# save the image with cv2
cv2.imwrite('test_cv2.png', state)
```

Then I tried reading in the image `test_mat.png` using `cv2.imread()` and the blob detector worked.

```py
im_cv2 = cv2.imread("test_mat.png")
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create()
print("im_cv2: ", im_cv2.shape, type(im_cv2))
keypoints = detector.detect(im_cv2)
print("Keypoints: ", keypoints)
if keypoints:
    print(keypoints[0].pt)
```

The output looks like:

```
im_cv2:  (237, 243, 3) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Keypoints:  [<KeyPoint 0x128a5b2a0>]
(102.55021667480469, 96.66270446777344)
```

However, when I tried using `cv2.imread()` to restore `test_cv2.png` (which is saved by using `cv2.imwrite()`), the blob detector failed.

```py
im_cv2 = cv2.imread("test_cv2.png")
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create()
print("im_cv2: ", im_cv2.shape, type(im_cv2))
keypoints = detector.detect(im_cv2)
print("Keypoints: ", keypoints)
if keypoints:
    print(keypoints[0].pt)
```

The output:

```
im_cv2:  (128, 128, 3) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Keypoints:  []
```

Also, using the variable `state` as input of `SimpleBlobDetector` didn't work either.

Comment: Does `test_cv2.png` look like what you expect?

Comment: The size of `test_mat.png` and `test_cv2.png` are different. Try to change the size of the detector or resize the image to be the same size. And see if the results are different.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith Yes, only the color is not as expected (in BGR order). I have tried to convert it to RGB order but it seems like it doesn't help either. 
@cel16 yes, when I tried to remove the margin of `test_mat.png`, the detector doesn't work either. So I guess the margin affects the result of the detector?

Comment: @cel16 I tried resizing the image and it works! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The blob detector has a specific minThreshold and maxThreshold. It seems like the blob you want to detect on test_cv2.png is smaller than the minimum size. You can change the parameters of the blob detector if you don't want to resize the image. [Blob Detection Examples](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/)